# Jenkins build project "Unable to access to repository"

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, visualsvn-server, visualsvn, ankhsvn

I am a complete Jenkins noob so if I have missed something completely obvious I apologise in advance!

I am building an intranet web application using Visual Studio 2010 and commit changes using AnkhSVN to a repository stored on a server that is running Visual SVN Server.

Due to budget restrictions this server is also acting as our web server and also running Jenkins. It is connected to our internal network but doesn't have external internet access so I have had to manually install Jenkins plugins and dependencies.

I am trying to build a Jenkins project that would build the web application when it detects a commit but when I enter the repository URL and the user credentials in the source code management window I get the following error message:

> Unable to access to repository

[image: Error message]

However when I enter the url in a browser and enter the same credentials I can access the repository without any errors.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Server Specs**

Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter 64bit

**Visual SVN Server**

Port: 443

Version 3.5.6

**Jenkins**

Port: 8080

Credentials Plugin 2.1.9
MapDB API Plugin 1.0.9.0
Pipeline: SCM Step 2.3
Pipeline: Step API 2.5
SCM API Plugin 1.3
SSH Credentials Plugin 1.12 
Structs Plugin 1.5
Subversion Plug-in 2.7.1

Answer (score 1):

check if the ip of jenkins server can access the svn ip server....i have the same problem  and i found that my ci server can not access the svn server .using ping command

Comment: Jenkins and visual svn are both on the same server

Answer (score 1):

That actually might be okay. For some reason I see similar error message (*could be a bug in Jenkins frontend*) when edit SCM details for a job in Jenkins, but it does work flawlessly if I actually save and run the job.

Give it a try it might actually work during the build time.